# Automate window programming through a base class

Tags: c++, constructor, widget, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have programmed several windows for an application that all inherit `Gtkmm::Window`. At this point, I would like to automate the process. Right now, the following structure stands out:

```
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MyWindow();
    virtual ~MyWindow();

    //...

private:
    void registerLayouts(); // Adds layouts to the window.
    void registerWidgets(); // Adds widgets to the layouts.

    //...
};
```

And the constructor:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    registerLayouts(); // Cannot be virtual: in constructor.
    registerWidgets(); // Cannot be virtual: in constructor.

    //...
}
```

So the problem is that all of this has to be done manually (i.e. copy/pasted) every time a new window has to be programmed because `registerLayouts()` and `registerWidgets()` are called at construction and hence cannot be `virtual`.

Ideally, I would have a base class that I could inherit from which would give me the option of overriding the two methods and would take care of the rest: it would call the two methods at an appropriate location.

The thing is, I have not found where this appropriate location could be. I have look at different signal handlers, but there seem to be none for this.

Do you have an idea of how I could do this?

MFC has the [`CDialog::OnInitDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ca64b77e-2cd2-47e3-8eff-c2645ad578f9.aspx#cdialog__oninitdialog) that performs something similar to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delegate the work to a separate class:

```
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
//public:  *** EDIT ***
protected:
    template <typename LayoutManager>
    MyWindow(LayoutManager const& lm)
    {
        lm.registerLayouts(this);
        lm.registerWidgets(this);
    }
};

class SubWindow : public MyWindow
{
    class LM { /* ... */ };
public:
     SubWindow() : MyWindow(LM()) { }
};
```

(Edited: The improved pattern hides away from public the layout managers of sub classes...)

Alternatively, the whole class as template <s>(possibly superior to above)</s>:

```
template <typename LayoutManager>
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MyWindow()
    {
        LayoutManager lm(*this);
        lm.registerLayouts();
        lm.registerWidgets();
    }
};

class SpecificLayoutManager { /* ... */ };
using SpecificWindow = MyWindow<SpecificLayoutManager>;
```

If you need the layout manager for cleaning up as well (not familiar with GTK myself...):

```
template <typename LayoutManager>
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    LayoutManager lm;
public:
    MyWindow() : lm(*this)
    {
        lm.registerLayouts();
        lm.registerWidgets();
    }
    virtual ~MyWindow()
    {
        // still access to lm...
    }
};
```

Important side note: In all variants we do *not yet* have a fully constructed derived class – casting to the latter within the layout managers thus is not legal (experimented with [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but dropped the idea for exactly the same reason: needed to cast to derived in constructor of base as well).

*Edit in response to comments:* A sample on how you could manage additional members of a subclass (using third variant above, the template class one with the layout manager member; `lm` member now needs to be `protected`):

```
class SubWindowLayoutManager
{
    template <typename>
    friend class MyWindow;
    friend class SubWindow;

    int someMember;

    void registerLayouts() { }
    void registerWidgets() { }

};
class SubWindow : public MyWindow<SubWindowLayoutManager>
{
    void doSomething()
    {
        lm.someMember = 77;
    }
};
```

Additionally a new variant entirely without templates:

```
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
protected:
    class LayoutManager
    {
    public:
         virtual void registerLayouts(MyWindow* parent) = 0;
         virtual void registerWidgets(MyWindow* parent) = 0;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<LayoutManager> lm;

    MyWindow(std::unique_ptr<LayoutManager> lm)
        : lm(std::move(lm))
    {
        this->lm->registerLayouts(this);
        this->lm->registerWidgets(this);
    }
};

class SubWindow : public MyWindow
{
    class LM : public LayoutManager
    {
    public:
        void registerLayouts(MyWindow* parent) override { }
        void registerWidgets(MyWindow* parent) override { }

        int someMember;
    };

    // convenience access function:
    inline LM& lm()
    {
        return *static_cast<LM*>(MyWindow::lm.get());
    }

public:
    SubWindow() : MyWindow(std::make_unique<LM>()) { }

    void doSomething()
    {
        //static_cast<LM*>(lm.get())->someMember = 77;
        lm().someMember = 77;
    }
};
```

Comment: I played with this a little tonight, but it did not work for me. I added one data member to `SubWindow` (I could be a widget, for instance) and tried to `cout` its value in the call to `registerLayouts`. I got it to compile, but the printed value is rubbish. I makes sense since at this point (inside the `MyWindow` constructor) there is no guarantee the `SubWindow` data members are handled. It seems like is suffers from the same problem I have with my virtual methods. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this the meaning of your last comment? If so this solution is not working for me because my `SubWindow` class will have widgets and other data member to handle.

Comment: @BobMorane Exactly. I added a sample how to use the third template variant to cover the issue; additionally a new variant getting along entirely without templates, using polymorphic layout managers. The nice thing about is that you don't need externally visible classes as with the template approach...